# why vscode is searching git instead of project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was performing full project search but the result just show show the git diff. Did I accidentally click some setting? How to bring back normal search?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so i assume you pressed ctrl + shift + f and after you searched you didn't get your answer ?
i cant open your image check it

Comment: yes, I press Cmd + shift + f, that what's what I used to do when I search project wide

Answer (score 0):

I clear all search result with the command pallete `clear search`

Now my result back to normal, no more searching git.